# LinkedIn API UGC Post Mention: share commentary is invalid

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I'm using LinkedIn API to create posts. I also use the [LinkedIn Mentions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api?tabs=http#mentions-in-ugc-posts) to create posts with mentions.

I can successfully create a post with mention except if I add in the message emojis or accents. Without mentions feature, I'm able to create any post with success.

**Posts that work:**

- Hello Stackoverflow
- Hello  Stackoverflow
- Hellóó Stackoverflow
- Hello Stackoverflow (with mention to the linkedin page)

**Posts that do not work:**

- Hello  Stackoverflow (with mention to the linkedin page)
- Hellóó Stackoverflow (with mention to the linkedin page)

I receive the following error:

> com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: share commentary is
> invalid

I send the following data to LinkedIn:

```
array (
  'author' => 'urn:li:organization:X',
  'lifecycleState' => 'PUBLISHED',
  'visibility' => 
  array (
    'com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility' => 'PUBLIC',
  ),
  'specificContent' => 
  array (
    'com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent' => 
    array (
      'shareCommentary' => 
      array (
        'text' => 'Hellóó Stackoverflow',
        'attributes' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'length' => 13,
            'start' => 8,
            'value' => 
            array (
              'com.linkedin.common.CompanyAttributedEntity' => 
              array (
                'company' => 'urn:li:organization:X',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'shareMediaCategory' => 'NONE',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `start` value could probably not match, when your text before contains multi-byte characters? (But `8` in your example above seems wrong to begin with, even if each character is counted as one position, it should be `7` in there, no?)

Comment: @CBroe one of the problems is solved, I was using "strpos" when I should use "mb_strpos" because of the accents & special chars. My problem is now only with emojis. I know that they should count as 2

Comment: _"I know that they should count as 2"_ - no, the number of bytes is likely to be more. https://3v4l.org/PDAop - strlen of  is shown as 4, so that's four bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

Three issues needed to be fixed:

- Switch from `strpos` to `mb_strpos`
- Switch from `strlen` to `mb_strlen`
- Count emojis in the body text as length 2, instead of 1

I'm now able to send text with accents, special chars & emojis with mentions.